# enumitem itemize items alignment

Tags: itemize, enumitem, alignment

I am very new to Latex so please be indulgent. I have a list of items, one of these items is a sentence that can go through multiple lines. I want this particular item to be justified and I can get the text to display within the same margin.

[image: exemple of output]

This is how the text should be (done manually)

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\bullet$]{\textbf{\u{v}}CC\textbf{\textschwa}C \ding{221} CC\textbf{\u{v}}C}
\item[$ $]{Lorem Ipsum : dolor sit amet}
\justifying
\item[$ $]{Lorem Ipsum : dolor sit amet, ius ex tollit deleniti iudicabit, id vivendum assueverit voluptatibus nec, ne feugiat dolorum vel. Dicat aeterno partiendo an cum, feugiat tibique nec te. Augue definitionem an pri.}
\item[$ $]{Lorem Ipsum :  dolor sit amet} \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a complete MWE from your code. Using your given code in a basic document does not show your problem. (And you do not need the curly braces around the item content.)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what is missing in my example. Do you mean the packages ?

Comment: Your document class, packages and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` are missing and should be included. See [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for further information on what a MWE is.

Comment: it's a special style sheet for a paper so I can't put all the documents here. I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 3):

No need to do `\item[$ $]` (and, by the way, `\item[]` would do the same). Set `\parsep` to zero and that's all: a blank line will do.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pifont,tipa}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[parsep=0pt]
\item \textbf{\u{v}}CC\textbf{\textschwa}C \ding{221} CC\textbf{\u{v}}C

      Lorem Ipsum: dolor sit amet

      Lorem Ipsum: dolor sit amet, ius ex tollit deleniti iudicabit, 
      id vivendum assueverit voluptatibus nec, ne feugiat dolorum vel. 
      Dicat aeterno partiendo an cum, feugiat tibique nec te. Augue
      definitionem an pri.

      Lorem Ipsum:  dolor sit amet
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine, have a look at this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[$\bullet$]{Hello world}
\item[$ $]{Lorem Ipsum : dolor sit amet}
\item[$ $]{Lorem Ipsum : dolor sit amet, ius ex tollit deleniti iudicabit, id vivendum assueverit voluptatibus nec, ne feugiat dolorum vel. Dicat aeterno partiendo an cum, feugiat tibique nec te. Augue definitionem an pri.}
\item[$ $]{Lorem Ipsum :  dolor sit amet}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I don't think you need to use justifying at all. I have remove some of the code regarding the first item, since they were causing some errors in the example, and replaced them with "Hello world".

[image]

Hope that helps.

Romain

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I am not sayin there is a bug. But it doesn't do what I want. I'm trying to have a block of text that is aligned. I'm not sure how to explain this with the proper words but I don't want the text to be in that margin.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the pdf generated by running the code above so you can see what it produces. It seems like what you did manually in your initial question?